# Flutter- Connecting to Python/Pytorch Backend

Tags: python, flutter, dart, pytorch

I'm building a mobile app using [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) that translates American Sign Language (ASL) to written English. As a prototype, I've limited my scope to translating photos of single alphanumeric characters. I have two parts to the project right now:

1. A python script that takes the path to an image, processes it with Torch/Torchvision and a custom model, and returns the alphanumeric character that is most likely to have been in the image. This part works great.
2. A Flutter front end that connects to the user's camera and saves the path to a taken image.

**Q: What is the best way to connect these two parts of my project?**

So far, I've tried two methods:

1. Using [Starflut](https://pub.dev/packages/starflut), which allows me to call Python code from Flutter and receive return values. I've tested it with some basic Python code (no dependencies) and it works great. However, for my more complex use case, where my Python code imports "torch", the code crashes.

Error Message:

```
:/data/data/com.example.asl/files/flutter_assets/starfiles/image_prediction.py, run failed

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

This happens when calling the following line of code:

```
    var result = await widget.srvGroup.loadRawModule("python", "",
    resPath + "/flutter_assets/starfiles/" + "image_prediction.py", false);
```

2. I've also tried [Pytorch_mobile Flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/pytorch_mobile), but beyond not being working exactly in the way I want and implemented in my own Python script, also crashes.

Error Message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.pytorch.IValue org.pytorch.Module.forward(org.pytorch.IValue[])' on a null object reference
```

This happens when calling the following line of code:

```
String prediction =
    await TorchMobile.getPrediction(_image, maxWidth: 256, maxHeight: 256);
```

Any suggestions as to how to get Starflut functioning would be ideal, as I'd like to use my Python interface, but if that's not possible, I'd love suggestions as to how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`starflut package` is used to compile python programs or any other scripting language in Flutter. This package will not help you to integrate your backend model with the application

To connect backend with your mobile application you'll have to write your own API or you can use `Pytorch_mobile` Flutter package.

Your app is crashing at -

```
String prediction =
    await TorchMobile.getPrediction(_image, maxWidth: 256, maxHeight: 256);
```

because it seems you forgot to initialize `_image`. Unfortunately, **NULL** is being stored in `_image`. So recheck your code where you've initialized `_image`.

To get a clear understanding you can definitely check out the following videos

- [Building An App From Scratch: Connecting Python Backend with Flutter Frontend | #5](https://youtu.be/k4FNxAGpAgg?list=PL5tVJtjoxKzrC1dRdj9AsRKcYO33pK76P)
- [How To Use Pytorch Mobile on Flutter](https://youtu.be/-II8B4DPZog)